# Why normalize when all features are on the same scale?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, normalization

So I'm doing the tensorflow tutorial found here:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_classification

Basically, my input is a [28x28] matrix (image) that I flatten to a [1x784] vector.

The tutorial then says:

> We scale these values to a range of 0 to 1 before feeding to the neural network model. For this, cast the datatype of the image components from an integer to a float, and divide by 255.

My question is why do we need to normalize in this case? My understanding is that when we have features that are on different scales, we need normalization if not the output of the model is distorted. But in this case all pixel ranges go from 0 to 255 (all features are the same scale)

I went ahead and ran it with normalization, and get an accuracy of over 85%, whereas no normalization, my accuracy falls to 10%.

Any ideas?

Comment: *Very* roughly speaking, this is because NNs and their corresponding activation functions work much better with ranges such as [0, 1]; but arguably this is not a *programming* question...

Comment: @desertnaut I can not believe that line of argument.Prior to the Activation function is the linear transformation. You can easily push normalisation in the transformation. Hence the activation function is not really effected - maybe gradient of though.. If you use plain gradient descent you just need to adjust the learning rate s.t. gradients are ok. I guess with other optimizers the problem is somehow related to that.

Comment: @CAFEBABE "You can easily push normalisation in the transformation" - yes, at least in theory, but the practice tells a different story; and I had clarified beforehand that I was speaking *very* roughly...

Comment: @desertnaut Never questioned that THE OPTIMIZERS work much better when TD is normalised. But you seem to agree that "speaking very roughly" means "has nothing to do with it but sounds good". If you know the true answer: sad because I would be curious.

Comment: @CAFEBABE I spoke in literally 15 words about "NNs and their corresponding activation functions", and given the "roughly speaking" part, this arguably included optimizers, too. I don't agree with what you think I seem to agree, and I really fail to see your point or the exact scope of this discussion...